# How to utilize multiple monitors with Microsoft Project 2010 (or other Office 2010 products)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, microsoft-office, microsoft-project

My question does primarily concern Project 2010, though it would be applicable to other Office products such as Excel, which can tend to span several horizontal screens.

Seems like an obvious question to me, but I had a hard time finding anyone else who had addressed this issue with Office products in specific (though there were several Google hits for the same question in Visual Studio).

With Project, I would love to be able to handle my task list in the left-hand screen, and see the corresponding Gantt chart laid out on the right-hand screen. For now, my solution has been to drag the window across both monitors, but that's sloppy and the Gantt chart does not zoom in/out correctly to account for the additional space.

It would also be nice to utilize this feature in Excel. As an engineer, I often track projects with spreadsheets that span 2-3 landscaped 11" x 17" pages. If I could spread the view over 2 screens it would make my life a lot easier.

Maybe there's a setting, or a 3rd party application that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what sort of desktop you have maximising the application will either fill one monitor or both.

For example the nVidia control panel has 5 choices but the two that are relevant are:

> 1. Choose the nView display mode to use.
>
>    - As one large horizontal desktop (Horizontal span)
>    - Configured independently from each other (Dualview)

In the first mode maximizing will (should) fill both monitors. In the second it just fills one.

You don't say what graphics card you have, but ATI have a similar option. So if you configure your desktop to be one large desktop then I think you should get what you want.

Comment: I have nVidia - and yeah I completely forgot about nView. I used it for about 30 minutes one day just to test it out then disabled and haven't used it again. Do you think it improves your productivity overall? I figured it was just bloatware sent with the graphics card, but I'll definitely try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Some Office programs, like Word, will open a new window automatically when you open a new file. Others do not. In most Office apps that don't automatically open a new window, the easiest thing to do is just launch a new instance of that program. I don't have Office communicator installed, but have tested this with both Excel and OneNote. Try this, and if it doesn't work, post in the comments and we can try to figure out another solution.

Comment: Yeah I often use this strategy with Excel and Word no problem, but Project 2010 no deals.

Answer (score -2):

An easy way to do this, with any program and without using Nvidia parameters, is to use Actiona, a free software.
Simply write two lines, one for dimensioning the window to 3840*1045, and one for moving the window to the point -1920:0.
Then you can export the program as an executable, so you can launch it whenever you want.